# Understanding AMCL, gmapping and hector_slam codebase and algorithms

Tags: slam, navigation, gmapping, hector-slam, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been able to successfully make fully autonomous AMCL based Robot and now want to explore in details the working of these nodes. My questions are:

1. Are there any advanced tutorials available to understand in detail the underlying algorithms of these nodes and how the codes work, in line with the navigation tutorials we have?
2. It seems most of the nodes are based on the [Probabilistic Robotics](https://docs.ufpr.br/%7Edanielsantos/ProbabilisticRobotics.pdf) book. Any suggestions on reading the book.
3. Are there any developer options to contribute and learn the codebase for these navigation algorithms?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258423/understanding-amcl,-gmapping-and-hector_slam-codebase-and-algorithms/) by [kartikmadhira1](https://answers.ros.org/users/28274/kartikmadhira1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2017-04-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've never come across ay "advanced" tutorials for amcl, gmapping, or hector_slam. However, I would strongly recommend reading Probabilistic Robotics. It covers the core components of amcl, and if your are not familiar with any of the subject matter then it should give you the prerequisite knowledge to understand the concepts behind gmapping, hector_slam, and many others. You could also look at the published papers for mapping, which is listed on the OpenSLAM site [here](https://www.openslam.org/gmapping.html) and the hector_slam paper which is listed on that package's wiki [here](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam).

As for contributing and learning the codebases, amcl and mapping are quite old, so there doesn't seem to much for active development currently. hector_slam is newer, so they may still be some development going on for that. My recommendation would be to study the theory, review the code to understand it, and follow any current issues on each packages github repo and see if you could contribute that way.

---

Originally posted by [Steven_Daniluk](https://answers.ros.org/users/25049/steven_daniluk/) with karma: 606 on 2017-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3